Nextcloud Nixos package, use databases MySQL or pgsql is not possible
The Nextcloud package is to be installed on a relatively new Nixos system. Which is no problem while using sqlite as db backend. But with MySQL or pgsql the setup of Nextcloud always dies. I have been trying for two days to find the right configuration.
Here is the minimum configuration I can think of that should work:
{ pkgs, ... }:
{

  # Set up the user in case you need consistent UIDs and GIDs. And also to make
  # sure we can write out the secrets file with the proper permissions.
  users.groups.nextcloud = { };
  users.users.nextcloud = {
    isSystemUser = true;
    group = "nextcloud";
  };

  services.nextcloud = {
    enable = true;
    hostName = "bfds";

# sqlite works like intended
#    database.createLocally = true;
#    config = {
#      dbtype = "sqlite";
#      adminpassFile = "/var/lib/nextcloud-pass-files/nc-admin-password";
#    };

# does not work
    config = {
      dbtype = "mysql";
      dbname = "nextcloud";
      dbhost = "localhost";
      dbpassFile = "/var/lib/nextcloud-pass-files/db-user-password"; 

      adminuser = "admin";
      adminpassFile = "/var/lib/nextcloud-pass-files/nc-admin-password";
    };

  };

  networking.firewall.allowedTCPPorts = [ 80 443 ];
}

The following error occurs:
nixos-rebuild switch
building Nix...
building the system configuration...
updating GRUB 2 menu...
activating the configuration...
setting up /etc...
reloading user units for sshuser...
setting up tmpfiles
warning: the following units failed: nextcloud-setup.service

× nextcloud-setup.service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/nextcloud-setup.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-05-28 21:36:10 UTC; 143ms ago
    Process: 111899 ExecStart=/nix/store/ifr79y87ngrasz99rc16pfww1i9v7c4y-unit-script-nextcloud-setup-start/bin/nextcloud-setup-start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 111899 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
         IP: 0B in, 0B out
        CPU: 142ms

May 28 21:36:10 bfds nextcloud-setup-start[111919]: #32 /nix/store/xldyix0vza99fz6z3q8bc7ks4kccz5rq-nextcloud-27.1.9/lib/private/AppFramework/Utility/SimpleContainer.php(138): Pimple\Container->offsetGet('OC\\Files\\Node\\H...')
May 28 21:36:10 bfds nextcloud-setup-start[111919]: #33 /nix/store/xldyix0vza99fz6z3q8bc7ks4kccz5rq-nextcloud-27.1.9/lib/private/ServerContainer.php(171): OC\AppFramework\Utility\SimpleContainer->query('OC\\Files\\Node\\H...', true)
May 28 21:36:10 bfds nextcloud-setup-start[111919]: #34 /nix/store/xldyix0vza99fz6z3q8bc7ks4kccz5rq-nextcloud-27.1.9/lib/private/AppFramework/Utility/SimpleContainer.php(65): OC\ServerContainer->query('OC\\Files\\Node\\H...')
May 28 21:36:10 bfds nextcloud-setup-start[111919]: #35 /nix/store/xldyix0vza99fz6z3q8bc7ks4kccz5rq-nextcloud-27.1.9/lib/private/Server.php(1493): OC\AppFramework\Utility\SimpleContainer->get('OC\\Files\\Node\\H...')
May 28 21:36:10 bfds nextcloud-setup-start[111919]: #36 /nix/store/xldyix0vza99fz6z3q8bc7ks4kccz5rq-nextcloud-27.1.9/lib/base.php(635): OC\Server->boot()
May 28 21:36:10 bfds nextcloud-setup-start[111919]: #37 /nix/store/xldyix0vza99fz6z3q8bc7ks4kccz5rq-nextcloud-27.1.9/lib/base.php(1196): OC::init()
May 28 21:36:10 bfds nextcloud-setup-start[111919]: #38 /nix/store/xldyix0vza99fz6z3q8bc7ks4kccz5rq-nextcloud-27.1.9/console.php(48): require_once('/nix/store/xldy...')
May 28 21:36:10 bfds nextcloud-setup-start[111919]: #39 /nix/store/xldyix0vza99fz6z3q8bc7ks4kccz5rq-nextcloud-27.1.9/occ(11): require_once('/nix/store/xldy...')
May 28 21:36:10 bfds systemd[1]: Failed to start nextcloud-setup.service.
May 28 21:36:10 bfds nextcloud-setup-start[111919]: #40 {main}
warning: error(s) occurred while switching to the new configuration

This is the error if the start up script is executed manually
# /nix/store/nb1ziwja6zdslgm01qwqcxrp0kmd3z1x-unit-script-nextcloud-setup-start/bin/nextcloud-setup-start
An unhandled exception has been thrown:
Doctrine\DBAL\Exception: Failed to connect to the database: An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in /nix/store/gs6ash7vjylgnrkra2a6waqccq0gvq0v-nextcloud-29.0.0/lib/private/DB/Connection.php:155
Stack trace:
#0 /nix/store/gs6ash7vjylgnrkra2a6waqccq0gvq0v-nextcloud-29.0.0/3rdparty/doctrine/dbal/src/Connection.php(453): OC\DB\Connection->connect()
#1 /nix/store/gs6ash7vjylgnrkra2a6waqccq0gvq0v-nextcloud-29.0.0/3rdparty/doctrine/dbal/src/Connection.php(411): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->getDatabasePlatformVersion()
#2 /nix/store/gs6ash7vjylgnrkra2a6waqccq0gvq0v-nextcloud-29.0.0/3rdparty/doctrine/dbal/src/Connection.php(318): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->detectDatabasePlatform()
#3 /nix/store/gs6ash7vjylgnrkra2a6waqccq0gvq0v-nextcloud-29.0.0/lib/private/DB/ConnectionAdapter.php(200): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->getDatabasePlatform()
#4 /nix/store/gs6ash7vjylgnrkra2a6waqccq0gvq0v-nextcloud-29.0.0/lib/private/DB/QueryBuilder/QueryBuilder.php(121): OC\DB\ConnectionAdapter->getDatabasePlatform()
#5 /nix/store/gs6ash7vjylgnrkra2a6waqccq0gvq0v-nextcloud-29.0.0/lib/private/AppConfig.php(1237): OC\DB\QueryBuilder\QueryBuilder->expr()
#6 /nix/store/gs6ash7vjylgnrkra2a6waqccq0gvq0v-nextcloud-29.0.0/lib/private/AppConfig.php(262): OC\AppConfig->loadConfig(false)
#7 /nix/store/gs6ash7vjylgnrkra2a6waqccq0gvq0v-nextcloud-29.0.0/lib/private/AppConfig.php(1378): OC\AppConfig->searchValues('enabled')
#8 /nix/store/gs6ash7vjylgnrkra2a6waqccq0gvq0v-nextcloud-29.0.0/lib/private/App/AppManager.php(131): OC\AppConfig->getValues(false, 'enabled')
#9 /nix/store/gs6ash7vjylgnrkra2a6waqccq0gvq0v-nextcloud-29.0.0/lib/private/App/AppManager.php(152): OC\App\AppManager->getInstalledAppsValues()
#10 /nix/store/gs6ash7vjylgnrkra2a6waqccq0gvq0v-nextcloud-29.0.0/lib/private/legacy/OC_App.php(234): OC\App\AppManager->getInstalledApps()
#11 /nix/store/gs6ash7vjylgnrkra2a6waqccq0gvq0v-nextcloud-29.0.0/lib/private/AppFramework/Bootstrap/Coordinator.php(90): OC_App::getEnabledApps()
#12 /nix/store/gs6ash7vjylgnrkra2a6waqccq0gvq0v-nextcloud-29.0.0/lib/base.php(706): OC\AppFramework\Bootstrap\Coordinator->runInitialRegistration()
#13 /nix/store/gs6ash7vjylgnrkra2a6waqccq0gvq0v-nextcloud-29.0.0/lib/base.php(1181): OC::init()
#14 /nix/store/gs6ash7vjylgnrkra2a6waqccq0gvq0v-nextcloud-29.0.0/console.php(48): require_once('/nix/store/gs6a...')
#15 /nix/store/gs6ash7vjylgnrkra2a6waqccq0gvq0v-nextcloud-29.0.0/occ(11): require_once('/nix/store/gs6a...')
#16 {main}

This is the failing script nextcloud-setup.service:
1 #!/nix/store/57dqrh5d96g2lriyyf81j53vzphfflh9-bash-5.2-p15/bin/bash
 2 set -e
 3 if [ ! -r "/var/lib/nextcloud-pass-files/db-user-password" ]; then
 4   echo "dbpassFile /var/lib/nextcloud-pass-files/db-user-password is not readable by nextcloud:nextcloud! Aborting..."
 5   exit 1
 6 fi
 7 if [ -z "$(</var/lib/nextcloud-pass-files/db-user-password)" ]; then
 8   echo "dbpassFile /var/lib/nextcloud-pass-files/db-user-password is empty!"
 9   exit 1
10 fi
11
12 if [ ! -r "/var/lib/nextcloud-pass-files/nc-admin-password" ]; then
13   echo "adminpassFile /var/lib/nextcloud-pass-files/nc-admin-password is not readable by nextcloud:nextcloud! Aborting..."
14   exit 1
15 fi
16 if [ -z "$(</var/lib/nextcloud-pass-files/nc-admin-password)" ]; then
17   echo "adminpassFile /var/lib/nextcloud-pass-files/nc-admin-password is empty!"
18   exit 1
19 fi
20
21 if [ -d "/var/lib/nextcloud"/nix-apps ]; then
22   echo "Cleaning up nix-apps; these are now bundled in the webroot store-path!"
23   rm -r "/var/lib/nextcloud"/nix-apps
24 fi
25 if [ -d "/var/lib/nextcloud"/apps ]; then
26   echo "Cleaning up apps; these are now bundled in the webroot store-path!"
27   rm -r "/var/lib/nextcloud"/apps
28 fi
29
30
31 # create nextcloud directories.
32 # if the directories exist already with wrong permissions, we fix that
33 for dir in /var/lib/nextcloud/config /var/lib/nextcloud/data /var/lib/nextcloud/store-apps; do
34   if [ ! -e $dir ]; then
35     install -o nextcloud -g nextcloud -d $dir
36   elif [ $(stat -c "%G" $dir) != "nextcloud" ]; then
37     chgrp -R nextcloud $dir
38   fi
39 done
40
41 ln -sf /nix/store/dlgngj03qajg7q76vj7ms6mh4hkvsxvz-nextcloud-config.php /var/lib/nextcloud/config/override.config.php
42
43 # Do not install if already installed
44 if [[ ! -e /var/lib/nextcloud/config/config.php ]]; then
45   export DBPASS="$(<"/var/lib/nextcloud-pass-files/db-user-password")"
46 export ADMINPASS="$(<"/var/lib/nextcloud-pass-files/nc-admin-password")"
47 /nix/store/n8zk09cawdjna7v9whradxxm7vij093x-nextcloud-occ/bin/nextcloud-occ maintenance:install \
48     --admin-pass "$ADMINPASS" \
49     --admin-user "admin" \
50     --data-dir "/var/lib/nextcloud/data" \
51     --database "mysql" \
52     --database-host "localhost" \
53     --database-name "nextcloud" \
54     --database-pass "$DBPASS" \
55     --database-user "nextcloud"
56
57 fi
58
59 /nix/store/n8zk09cawdjna7v9whradxxm7vij093x-nextcloud-occ/bin/nextcloud-occ upgrade
60
61 /nix/store/n8zk09cawdjna7v9whradxxm7vij093x-nextcloud-occ/bin/nextcloud-occ config:system:delete trusted_domains
62
63
64
65 /nix/store/n8zk09cawdjna7v9whradxxm7vij093x-nextcloud-occ/bin/nextcloud-occ config:system:set trusted_domains \
66   0 --value="bfds"

